# external link to a div on a one page bootstrap site

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I am building a one page site and the divs are set to sweep in horizontally using jQuery and CSS.

link to site http://97squared.co.uk/starstruck-roadshow.co.uk/

the problem I have is that I want to be able to link to sections of the site (blog etc) from external sources. Currently the divs are brought to the browser window by calling the id of the div in the href, for example

`<a href='#about-us' class=scrollitem'>About Us</a>`

but if I try to access that div from an external link for example

```
http://http://97squared.co.uk/starstruck-roadshow.co.uk/#about-us
```

or

```
http://97squared.co.uk/starstruck-roadshow.co.uk/index.php#about-us
```

it doesn't take me to the relevant div on the page.

If anybody has any idea how I can get around this via .htaccess rewrites or jQuery redirects then please help, I am tearing my hair out

Comment: you'd need to (on load) check for the presence of a hash value and trigger a scroll/animation to the appropriate point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok figured it out with help from the others on here

I used @pattie  var hash = window.location.hash; and mixed with my code got it to work.

```
        var hash = window.location.hash;    
        var sildeNum = $('.page').length,
          wrapperWidth = 100 * sildeNum,
          slideWidth = 100/sildeNum;
        $('.wrapper').width(wrapperWidth + '%'); 
        $('.page').width(slideWidth + '%');
        var slideNumber = $(hash).index('.page'),           
            margin = slideNumber * -100 + '%';
        $('.wrapper').animate({marginLeft: margin},500);                    
        return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```